# Can't change color on css a:hover with a colorpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```css
ul li {
  width: auto;
  display: inline;
}
#demo {
    text-align:right;
    font-size:20px;
    color:black;
    background-color:none;
    margin:2px;
}
.buttonnt1 {
    background-color: #3CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 22px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #333;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
ul > li:last-child ul{
    right: 4px;
    left: auto;
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.colorhover a:hover {
  background-color: var(--c,#4CAF50);
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li id="English"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li id="Svenska" class="dropdown">
</li>
  <li id="English" class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn colorhover" ondblclick="getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()" onclick="myFunction()">What is the time</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Double click to show what time it is</a>
    </div>
</li>
    <li id="English" class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Support</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://www.404.com">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">Location</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

I can't change color on `a:hover {background-color:#333;}` with a color picker http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/. How can i change color on :hover with a color picker. If i just use `a` it  changes `<a>`. If i make a class `.colorhover a:hover {background-color:#333;}` a:hover don't work at all.

`a.colorhover:hover` Does not work either.

How can i make it to work with a:hover.

```
$('#colorpickerHolder').ColorPicker({
color: '#0000ff',
onShow: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
    return false;
},
onHide: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
    return false;
},
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
   $('a:hover').css("background", "#" + hex);
}
```

Comment: `$('a:hover')` does not change the value for it. There is no easy way to change the style in the stylesheet. Either set and remove the color with jquery's hover / mouseenter/mouseleave or dynamiclaly add a style rule.

Comment: you could try `$('a').on('mouseenter', function() { $(this).css('background','#'+ hex); })` and then do one for mouseleave too but why wouldn't you just use css for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider CSS variable:

```js
onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
  $('.colorhover').css("--c", "#" + hex);
}
```

```css
.colorhover a:hover {
  background-color: var(--c,#333);
}
```

Comment: @WoDoQoCO are you using the V3 of jQuery or the V2 ?

Comment: it was v1.3.2 should i download V3 or V2

Comment: @WoDoQoCO for CSS variable you need to use the V3

Comment: can you show me a full working code? jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: Can I send you a zip file.

Comment: @WoDoQoCO is it working ? :) I still didn't check all the code

Comment: No its not working just sent it so you can see if something is wrong

Comment: @WoDoQoCO ma checking your JS and it's not good ... you are repeating the same thing many times `$('#colorpickerHoldderr').ColorPicker({` you are overriding it each time

Comment: on this  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" ondblclick="getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()" onclick="myFunction()">What is the time</a> you have to add colorhover on class so you can see the change it changes the color on the <a> element but it doesn't add it to the hover effect

Comment: becouse i want to change color on different classes and elements

Comment: @WoDoQoCO yes but actually you are targetting the same element, you need to target different element ... your selector is selecting by ID

Comment: Okey, but how to fix so that i can change color on :hover. This css code are not working becouse there is no hover color at all                                                           
  .colorhover a:hover {
  background-color: var(--c,#4CAF50);
}

Comment: @WoDoQoCO well, here is a simplifed version of the code https://jsfiddle.net/7a3uy62p/ .. hover the link and see the color, then click the button and hover again to see the color changes .. the code is working fine but the issue is within your code, you are not using the library in a good way

Comment: When a used the old jquery v1.3.2. and changed colorpickerHolder to a different name like colorover it didnt work no colorpicker showed at all. But now its working when i used v3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to "select" a CSS style with jQuery. jQuery has its own selectors, many of which do overlap with CSS, but they are not the same.

Here you can see that `:hover` is not a valid jQuery selector: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

It is a valid [CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).

You could define the behavior you want using jQuery's [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/), which has callbacks for `handlerIn` and `handlerOut`.

You haven't provided the markup (and CSS?) for your code so I don't have a working example for you. You could edit your post with a snippet that shows your working code so far. (See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))